# Running ArcGIS RunTime Map With C# Code on WPF?

Tags: arcgis-runtime-sdk-.net

I have a WPF application called WpfApplication1. In ManiWindow.xaml I have a

Snippet

```
<esri:MapView x:Name="MyMapView">            

</esri:MapView>
```

and in ManiWindow.xmal.cs I only have

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {

            InitializeComponent();

        }

    }
}
```

According to ESRI we can add the Map to the MapView as as long as we have an empty MapView has been added to the page at design time and has been given the name `MyMapView (<esri:MapView x:Name="MyMapView"/>`.

Now my question is how/ where should I add this code to get map running?

```
// create a new Map 
var myMap = new Esri.ArcGISRuntime.Controls.Map();

// create a new layer (world street map tiled layer)
var uri = new Uri("http://services.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/World_Street_Map/MapServer");
var baseLayer = new Esri.ArcGISRuntime.Layers.ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer(uri);
// (give the layer an ID so it can be found later)
baseLayer.ID = "BaseMap";

// add the layer to the Map
myMap.Layers.Add(baseLayer);

// set the initial view point
var mapPoint = new Esri.ArcGISRuntime.Geometry.MapPoint(-117.445, 33.9, 
    Esri.ArcGISRuntime.Geometry.SpatialReferences.Wgs84);
var initViewPoint = new Esri.ArcGISRuntime.Controls.ViewpointCenter(mapPoint, 250000);

myMap.InitialViewpoint = initViewPoint;

// assign the Map to the MapView's Map property
this.MyMapView.Map = myMap;
```

Comment: Where exactly have you put that part? <esri:MapView x:Name="MyMapView"> </esri:MapView>

Comment: <esri:MapView x:Name="MyMapView">            

</esri:MapView>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends which design pattern you want to implement. Some people prefer to keep the MainWindow.cs file clean of code, in which case you should look into how to create a ViewModel class. That is a more advanced topic that is covered here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798384.aspx

If you just want to get things up and running quick, then the code you have included at the bottom can either go in the constructor of the MainWindow class `public MainWindow() { }`, or in a separate method within the same class. Insert this code after the call to `InitializeComponent();`. Since the code behind inherits from the XAML markup, it will recognize the MapView object when you declare it as `this.MyMapView.Map;`

The Xaml file and the .cs file have different rules regarding how they share variables. I would encourage you to read into [how data binding works in WPF.](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/data-binding/hello-bound-world/)

Comment: Thanks a lot Andrew, So in case of using MVVM I need to use data binding procedure? Correct?

Comment: Yes, you can set the data context in the code behind or in the xaml. I like to do it in the code behind just in case I need to sneak some event handlers in there for some reason. But for the most part, I prefer the ICommand pattern for responding to map events.